# How to authenticate phone number with azure sql database on Android?

Tags: android, azure

Is there a way to authenticate phone number in azure with android SDK ? On Firebase there is an API to authenticate your phone number without any issue but I am not too sure on how to implement the same idea into android with azure.

```
var mobile = feTable.where().field("handphone").eq("91234567").execute().get()
                for(f in mobile){
                    if(f!= null)
                    Log.i("Logger", f.mobile)
                }
```

The code above is how I tried to query but it ended up leading the whole application to hang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Log.v("Logger:", "Table name : ${feTable.tableName}")
                val result: JsonElement =
                    feTable.where().field("handphone").eq(phoneNumber).execute().get()

                val results: JsonArray = result.asJsonArray

                var length = results.count()

                if (length != 1) {
                    Log.v("Logger", "Number of user: $length")
                    throw Exception("User not found or cannot query the database")
                }
```

According to the documentation posted by Microsoft. The only way is to query through async. So I did it by getting the phone number of the editText and count the number of rows data that I had queried.

> Since each phone number is unique

If there is found to be more/less than 1 phone number in the row, it will throw an error